# Do radiator covers harm heating efficiency?

Tags: radiator

I am considering radiator covers, maybe wood slats with a foil back that will prevent towards-wall radiation.

How much will this harm the heating efficiency of the radiators?

Comment: Without a picture if what your trying to do its almost impossible to say.  Remember tho the heat rises and that air flow is important-heat creates convection-dont block the airflow.

Answer (score 2):

Radiators heat by convection and radiation. The radiation output will be affected by the amount of radiated surface you cover and the convection process will be affected by how much you reduce the air flow around and thru the radiators. If the covers reduce the heat output too much you may have to increase the size of the radiators or add more heating surface. (another radiator or a larger radiator) The amount of heating reduction will be determined by the construction of the covers. Covers that have a closed top will reduce the output by as much as 30%. Design is everything.

Comment: Showing a picture of the existing radiators and explaining what type and the construction of the covers will help to determine how much heating effect you will loose.